# Insert two columns in a data frame from another data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I am working on an election dataset, in which I want to show which party has a higher representative in each district. For this I want to show it on the map of Pakistan. The election dataset has no info about the lat/lon. I found another dataset that has this info. I do not know how to merge this dataset so I can show my result on the map of Pakistan.

```
df1
city       lat      lon
karachi    24.860   67.010
lahore     31.549   74.3436
sialkot    32.50    74.53


election_df2 
District   Seat     ConstituencyTitle     CandidateName     Party     Votes
Karchi     Karachi    NA249               sajid abdullah     pmln     80000
lahore     lahore     NA129               firdous ashiq      pppp     50010
sialkot    sialkot    NA150               ahsan iqbal        pmln     45000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["karachi",24.860,67.010],["lahore",31.549,74.3436],["sialkot",32.50,74.53]],columns=["city","lat","lon"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Karachi","pmln",80000],["lahore","pppp",50010],["sialkot","pmln",45000]],columns=["Seat","Party","Votes"])
df2["city"] = df2.Seat.str.lower()
df3 = df2.merge(df1,on='city')
print(df3)
```

output

```
      Seat Party  Votes     city     lat      lon
0  Karachi  pmln  80000  karachi  24.860  67.0100
1   lahore  pppp  50010   lahore  31.549  74.3436
2  sialkot  pmln  45000  sialkot  32.500  74.5300
```

Note: I use subset of your data for brevity sake. **Disclaimer** this solution assumes lat and lon is known for each Seat.